# HTTP through a domain socket

Tags: http, sockets, unix-socket

I'm writing a bit of desktop software which has two components. Component B queries component A. Creating a web service seems like an ideal way to do IPC in principle. The data model fits, there are ready-made client and server libraries, a well known way to encode and decode parameters etc.

But setting up an HTTP server on a network socket doesn't seem right for a local application. For example what port do I choose? I don't really want people to be able to scan and talk to the app from outside etc.

So I was thinking that I might be able to do HTTP over a domain socket. Does that make any sense? Is there any precedence for it? Is there an equivalent protocol that I could use for IPC which has the same properties as HTTP (requests for specified resources (URIs), encoded parameters, response)?

Looking for C libraries (and possibly Go and ObjC for bonus points).

Answer (score 0):

Binding to the loopback interface only (127.0.0.1) solves your "external visibility" problem, only processes on the local machine will be able to connect.

It does not solve your port allocation problem though, the port number you choose might be taken by the time your app starts. Then your server can't bind and your client connects to the other process bound to your port.

Old, less hip, but CORBA implementations tend to have the problems you have not thought of yet figured out already.

Comment: I'm aware of CORBA lurking in the background, but with C on one side and and Obj-C on the either ... I don't need to finish that sentence.

Comment: Actually, that's what CORBA is (was?) for, cross-platform IPC locally or across the network. There are libraries for both languages. You'll end up reimplementing a lot of it by the time you are done with web services.

Comment: I will give it a serious look, thanks. From an initial skim of the wikipedia article the requirements for C implementation seem like a lot of hassle, but as you say probably no more than putting together an HTTP response.

Comment: One advantage of AF_UNIX over the loopback interface is that the socket can be protected by standard Unix permissions. For local applications this might be better than doing authentication over the wire.  Or it might not, depends on the application, and I have never tried HTTP over AF_UNIX.